# Angular 9 on mobile: Error: Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise

Tags: angular9

When I launch my application on the mobile chrome simulator or even on a smartphone (chrome or safari) I have this error, not on the desktop:

```
Error: Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten.
Most likely cause is that a Promise polyfill has been loaded after Zone.js (Polyfilling Promise api is not necessary when zone.js is loaded. If you must load one, do so before loading zone.js.)
    at Function.Zone.assertZonePatched (zone.js:68)
    at new NgZone (core.js:40989)
    at getNgZone (core.js:42356)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModuleFactory (core.js:42169)
    at core.js:42250
    at es.promise.js:114
```